# Just help me understand this code. i just want to ge comments to my posts. i already know how to store comments along with the key id's

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

i just want to get the comments working on my template, i'm new to python programming and especially using templates. But its all like php so i'm getting a hang of it. i'm using jinja templating engine and this code shows how to get comments but i cant get it to work.it gives me a 405 error. could you please expound on it further?

```
def get_comments(posts):
    postids = []
    for post in posts:
        postids.append(post.key().id())
    comments = {}
    for i in postids:
        comments[i] = Comment.all().ancestor(Blogpost.get_by_id(i))
    return comments
```

and in templates

```
{% for comment in comments[entry.key().id()] %}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your title to reflect a better summary of your question. Short and terse.

Comment: I retagged to include `jinja2`.  You didn't specify, but I assume that you're using `jinja2`, not `jinja`, right?

Comment: You are querying wrong in my opinion. You need the keys.

Answer (score 0):

First if using ndb ancestors you need keys

```
def get_comments(posts):        
    comments = []
    for post in posts:
        comments.append(Comment.query(ancestor=post.key()).get())
    return comments
```

And template it (example)

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{{ comment.title }}
```

Hope this solves it.

Comment: it still doesn't work. do you of any example you can link me to?

Comment: @kevinoutsideboxthinker Post your console or browser message. Also check updated answer about templating. Post as much code as you can for people to help you here.

Comment: @kevinoutsideboxthinker if you are OK with it also mark the answer of your choice as valid. And welcome to StackOverflow